# TFS build errors a file not found, while file exists

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfsbuild

I am having issue with TFS build server 2013, where during the build process, it fails to copy certain files, while the files exist in the TFS repository.

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\...\v12.0\..\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "www\public\modules\xxx.tmpl.html" because it was not found.
```

The files do exist and have been accessed and modified by multiple developers, all using VS 2013 pro.

Would anybody have encountered this before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this part of a custom build step? Something in one of your build `.proj` \ project `.csproj` files?

Comment: We are using the default build template, and it is failing pulling the files. I went through the project file a few times but nothing was really modified theren or customized.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me, have you tried turning the logging verbosity upto diagnostic and looking at the MSBuild logs?

Comment: Where on disk is that file? "www\" does not sound like a valid location.